# How to encode NDEF message

Tags: android, cordova, utf-8, nfc, ndef

This is the first time, I am working `NFC` based feature. I am facing a problem regarding encoding NDEF message.

we tried 2 apps to write data into NFC tag, names are `NDEF and TagWriter`. I am writing my data into text format.This is what my data

```
{name:myTag,tagDetails:{name:"myOrganization",addess:"xxxxx"}}
```

What I understand, both apps are encoding and injecting data into tag.The problem was while reading time.

Once I read tag, I am converting bytes to String like `nfcEvent.tag.ndefMessage[0].payload`.

What are the tags written by `NDEF App`, after converting exact data coming what I written into tag.
The problem with `TagWritter`, After converting this tags data, it's coming in this format.

```
 "en"{name:myTag,tagDetails:{name:"myOrganization",addess:"xxxxx"}}""
```

Regarding this, I did some research What I found `TagWritter App` converting data into `UTF-8` format.

I think because of this it's happening. may be I might wrong.

how can I solve this issue.

Note : I am using `Apache cordova` to build android application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you see something like "en" (actually a non-pritable character + a language code) prepended to your data, this suggests that your tag writer app placed the text string into an NFC Forum Text record (you can get the specification from the [NFC Forum's website](http://nfc-forum.org/)).

The record consists of a status byte, a language code (in US-ASCII) followed by the actual text. The upper bit (b7) of the status byte indicates if the text is encoded in UTF-8 (b7 = `0`) or UTF-16 (b7 = `1`). The lower 6 bits (b5..0) indicate the length of the language code in bytes.

So as long as the language code is 2 bytes, your solution of trimming the first three bytes will work.

However, the NFC Forum Text record type is specifically intended for human-readable text and you should probably avoid using it to store JSON objects. It would be better to use an NFC Forum external type record (or a custom MIME type record) to store your data.

Answer (score 0):

I seen the plugin documentation,what I am using to read(`chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc`). They itself suggesting to remove unnecessary characters. So we have to write code thi format.

```
   nfc.bytesToString(nfcEvent.tag.ndefMessage[0].payload).substring(3);
```

This is the [link](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/master/doc/GettingStarted.md), I seen